# Combining data from two partially overlapping access tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables with the same number of columns

[Uncombined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G81v.png)

This is a sample of the kind of output that can happen.  As you can see there is some overlap(193 is in both).  I have tried a left join, right join, and both using a union but I can't get all the information to exist as one.  The best I can get is this

[Combined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7sVR.png)

How do I combine the ProdSys columns into one(if they match) but keep the two other columns the way they are.

```
SELECT NewCoAvgCalcFull.ProdSys, NewCoAvgCalcPartial.ProdSys, NewCoAvgCalcFull.CO_Average, NewCoAvgCalcPartial.CO_Average 
FROM NewCoAvgCalcFull 
LEFT JOIN NewCoAvgCalcPartial 
ON NewCoAvgCalcFull.ProdSys = NewCoAvgCalcPartial.ProdSys 
UNION 
SELECT NewCoAvgCalcFull.ProdSys, NewCoAvgCalcPartial.ProdSys, NewCoAvgCalcFull.CO_Average, NewCoAvgCalcPartial.CO_Average 
FROM NewCoAvgCalcFull 
RIGHT JOIN NewCoAvgCalcPartial 
ON NewCoAvgCalcFull.ProdSys = NewCoAvgCalcPartial.ProdSys;
```

Comment: I don't understand what that means.  I tried a union and a union all

Comment: This gets me close to what I want
SELECT NewCoAvgCalcFull.ProdSys, NewCoAvgCalcPartial.ProdSys, NewCoAvgCalcFull.CO_Average, NewCoAvgCalcPartial.CO_Average
FROM NewCoAvgCalcFull LEFT JOIN NewCoAvgCalcPartial ON NewCoAvgCalcFull.ProdSys = NewCoAvgCalcPartial.ProdSys

UNION

SELECT NewCoAvgCalcFull.ProdSys, NewCoAvgCalcPartial.ProdSys, NewCoAvgCalcFull.CO_Average, NewCoAvgCalcPartial.CO_Average
FROM NewCoAvgCalcFull RIGHT JOIN NewCoAvgCalcPartial ON NewCoAvgCalcFull.ProdSys = NewCoAvgCalcPartial.ProdSys;

Comment: So you want 3 columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT nacf.ProdSys, nacf.CO_Average as full_co_average, NULL as partial_co_average
FROM NewCoAvgCalcFull as nacf
UNION ALL
SELECT nacp.ProdSys, NULL, nacp.CO_Average
FROM NewCoAvgCalcPartial as nacp;
```

EDIT:

The above creates two rows when there is a match in each table.  Perhaps you really want:

```
SELECT nacf.ProdSys, nacf.CO_Average as full_co_average,
       nacp.CO_Average as partial_co_average
FROM NewCoAvgCalcFull as nacf LEFT JOIN
     NewCoAvgCalcPartial as nacp
     on nacp.ProdSys = nacf.ProdSys
UNION ALL
SELECT nacp.ProdSys, NULL, nacp.CO_Average
FROM NewCoAvgCalcPartial as nacp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM NewCoAvgCalcFull as nacf
                  WHERE nacf.ProdSys = nacp.ProdSys
                 );
```

Comment: When I try to run this query it tells me there is a syntax error in the FROM clause.  I am not that great with SQL but looking over what you wrote looks fine to me so I am not sure what it wants?  Also, thank you for taking the time to come up with this query.

Comment: @Jeebwise . . . The query had `as nacp as nacp` for one of the aliases.  Fixed now.

Comment: Excellent.  That worked perfectly.  I just had to alter one more piece "nacp.ProdSys = nacp.ProdSys"  I had to make it nacf.ProdSys = nacp.ProdSys.  Now it comes up exactly as I need it to look